# Remove intersecting points from polygon

Tags: r, clip, polygons, r-sp

I am trying to create a new set of `SpatialPoints` from the `gDifference` of two `sp` geometries. Suppose the following:

You have two `SpatialPolygons`:

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

#Create SpatialPlygons objects
polygon1 <- readWKT("POLYGON((-190 -50, -200 -10, -110 20, -190 -50))")          
#polygon 1
polygon2 <- readWKT("POLYGON((-180 -20, -140 55, 10 0, -140 -60, -180 -20))") #polygon 2

#Plot both polygons
par(mfrow = c(1,2)) #in separate windows
plot(polygon1, main = "Polygon1") #window 1
plot(polygon2, main = "Polygon2") #window 2
```

Now, you want to get the `gDifference` between them:

```
polygon_set <- readWKT(paste("POLYGON((-180 -20, -140 55, 10 0, -140 -60, -180 -20),",
                             "(-190 -50, -200 -10, -110 20, -190 -50))"))

par(mfrow = c(1,1)) #now, simultaneously
plot(polygon_set, main = "Polygon1 & Polygon2")


clip <- gDifference(polygon2, polygon1, byid = TRUE, drop_lower_td = T) #clip polygon 2 with polygon 1
plot(clip, col = "red", add = T)
```

[image]

How can I get a `sp` geometry with only the non-intersecting points of the `polygon2` (i.e., the red points in the following image)?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: turn them into individual lines and test for intersection then pick the ones that don't?

Comment: I have tried that, but the whole `polygon2` is returned. I assume that it only consider intersection when the whole line is "contained"

Comment: After you [determine the points of intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519431/finding-point-of-intersection-in-r), you need to determine the ordering that produces the desired polygon.  The `ggplot2::fortify` function will give a nice data.frame for your use in plotting, after you adjust the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comparison of the coords of `clip` and `polygon2` gives you the non-intersecting points.

```
library(ggplot2)                         # as @shayaa commented, ggplot2::fortify is useful.

clip_coords <- fortify(clip)[,1:2]          # or, clip@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
polygon2_coords <- fortify(polygon2)[,1:2]  # or, polygon2@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
duplicated_coords <- merge(clip_coords, polygon2_coords) 
  # duplicated_coords is the non-intersecting points of the polygon2
res <- SpatialPoints(duplicated_coords)

plot(clip)
plot(res, col="red", pch=19, add=T)
```

[image]

#### [ Additional code : ver. intersecting points (suppose above code has run) ]

```
## an independent method
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)

clip2 <- gIntersection(polygon2, polygon1, byid = TRUE, drop_lower_td = T)
res2.1 <- fortify(clip2)[,1:2] %>% setdiff(polygon2_coords) %>%   # not_duplicated_coords
  SpatialPoints()


## a method usign a gDifference.sp.coords
res2.2 <- fortify(clip2)[,1:2] %>% merge(clip_coords) %>% 
  distinct() %>% SpatialPoints()    # res2.2 is equal to res2.1 in elements.


plot(polygon_set, main = "Polygon1 & Polygon2")
plot(clip2, col="red", add=T)
plot(res2.1, col="blue", pch=19, add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: I used `tidy` instead of `fortify`, the outcomes remains equal. I have been trying the same code to get the `gIntersection` **and not the `gDifference`**, but the resulting `sp` object is clip and not the `SpatialPoints` of the polygon. `merge(clip_coords, polygons2_coords, all.x = T)` do not work.

Comment: OK, I edited. Is this the answer you were hoping for ?