# How to find when a curve is above another curve

Tags: r, intersection, curves

I am trying to identify the points on the graph below where line2 reaches a point above or below line 1. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: can you provide a mcve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver

Comment: You need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you really want help. Ideally some sample input data and the desired result for that data so solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519431/finding-point-of-intersection-in-r